# Proof of direct sum decomposition of a vector space via a projection

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\varphi :V \rightarrow V$ be an homomorphism with $\varphi\circ \varphi=\varphi$, $U_1=\{\varphi(v) |v\in V\}$, $U_2=\{v-\varphi(v) |v\in V\}$.

I have to prove (1) $V=U_1+U_2$ and (2) $U_1\cap U_2={0}$

**The Proof**

*(1)*

$$\begin{align*}
U_1+U_2&=\{φ(v)  | v∈V\}+\{v-φ(v)  | v∈V\}\\
&=\{φ(v)+(v-φ(v))  | v∈V\}\\
&=\{v | v∈V\}\\
&=V\end{align*}$$

*(2)*

Let $u\in U_1\cap U_2$. This means that $u\in U_1=\{\varphi(v) |v\in V\}$ and therefore $\exists v\in V : u=\varphi(v)$. Furthermore $\exists v'\in V : u=v'-\varphi(v')$. We can conclude:

$\varphi(v)=v'-\varphi(v') \Leftrightarrow \varphi(v)+\varphi(v')=v' \Leftrightarrow \varphi(v+v')=v'$

However I'm not sure how I can finish (2) and is (1) correct?

Comment: "Proof" is a noun. The verb is "to prove".

Comment: Note: although your first equality just happens to be true, it is false in general. In general, $\{f(x)\mid x\in V\} + \{g(x)\mid x\in V\}$ is **not** equal to $\{f(x)+g(x)\mid x\in V\}$. That's because in the latter, the same $x$ must be used for both functions, whereas the first sum you would also include terms of the form $f(x)+g(y)$ with $x\neq y$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) is almost correct. As others have already mentioned in the comments, you have $V \subseteq U_1 + U_2$, but obviously $U_1 + U_2 \subseteq V$, since $U_1 = \mathrm{im} \varphi$ and $U_2 = \ker \varphi$. To prove (2), just apply $\varphi$ on both sides of your equality to get $u =\varphi(v) = 0$.

Comment: There is a problem with (1): the second equality does not follow from general principles (you only get $\supseteq$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Fair point. Yes, you only get $\supseteq$.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek when I apply $\varphi$ on both sides I get $\varphi(v+v')=\varphi(v') \Leftrightarrow v+v'=v' \Leftrightarrow v=0$. How can I conclude that $\varphi(v)=\varphi(0)=0$?

Comment: @locovog No, the first equivalence is wrong if $\varphi$ is not injective. You have $\varphi(v + v') = \varphi(v') \Leftrightarrow \varphi(v) + \varphi(v') = \varphi(v') \Leftrightarrow \varphi(v) = 0$.

Comment: Oh yeah, alright thank you! One more question. How did I show $V\subseteq U_1+U_2$ with (1)? The equality isn't always true so I'm not sure about this point...

Comment: @locovog: It is always true that your second line is contained in the first line. What is not always true is that the first line is contained in the second.

Comment: Ah yeah ok. Thank you very much!